# How to programatically set management server port for Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Is there a simple way to set `management.server.port` programmatically, based on the `management.server` value? I would like to set

```
management.server.port=${server.port + 2}
```

What I was thinking is creating http connector manually for actuator but it is a lot of afford.

Comment: management.server.port=${PORT:0} will create dynamic port numbers

Comment: @Prasobh.Kollattu but I don't want to have it dynamic, I wan't to control it and have it set based on the `server.port` property

Comment: then how do you figure out admin server port?..Admin server port should be predefined and all services can take random port..

Answer (score 1):

You can tune the environment on startup using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor`. This will work as long as you don't see `server.port` to `0`. When you do that, the underlying connector is responsible to allocate a random, free port and that will happen after the environment has been prepared.

The idea behind the implementation is to read the value of `server.port`, apply whatever logic you need and set a `management.server.port` property.

There is more explanation and a sample in the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-boot-application.html#howto-customize-the-environment-or-application-context).